# How to list all local images on a Kubernetes node (AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Our deployment's `imagePullPolicy` wasn't set for a while, which means it used `IfNotPresent`.
If I understand correctly, each k8s node stored the images locally so they can be reused on the next deployment if necessary.

Is it possible to list/show all the stored local images per node in an AKS cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As docker is installed on every node of the k8s cluster, to list/show local images per node, you need login to the worker node and you could run :

```
    docker images
```

This would give you the list of all the images on that particular node.

Comment: we are running on an AKS (edited), how can I access it there?

Comment: AKS now doesn't use docker so you won't be able to use this.

Comment: Yes. AKS now doesn't use docker. There are no docker command available in node.

Answer (score 5):

AKS uses containerd-shim
[image]

For listing out the container images on AKS *docker-cli* is unavailable, use **crictl** instead. It is located at

```
ls /usr/local/bin
bpftrace  crictl  health-monitor.sh  kubectl  kubelet
```

Use **crictl images** to list out container images on AKS worker nodes.

Debugging on k8s with [crictl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/)

[Man page crictl](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md)

Other [cri-tools](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools) info

Getting shell into a node with [krew-plugins](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew) by using [node-shell](https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-node-shell)

Other Krew [Plugins](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/)

Answer (score -1):

Per [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-all-container-images-in-all-namespaces) the solution should be to list all images of all running containers (though this does not list pulled images that are not currently used) :

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you have to firstly check the node to which pod has been scheduled against that microservice.

```
kubectl -n namespace get pods -o wide
```

Once you get the node, try to setup an ssh connection with the node, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) link can be used to do it.

Then you can execute following command in that VM

```
docker images
```

It will give you all docker images in that